# oracle DDL tracking logminer not showing "username"."object_name" in sql ddl statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have already done the following:
1. force logging yes

2. supplmental_log_data_min, supplemental_log_data_pk, supplemental_log_data_all       yes
3. archive mode on
4. added log files using `dbms_logmnr.add_logfiles(logfilename=>'filename');`
5. started logmnr using

   ```
   dbms_logmnr.start_logmnr(options=>dbms_logmnr.dict_from_redo_logs +
                                  dbms_logmnr.ddl_dict_tracking +
                                  dbms_logmnr.committed_data_only,
                         startscn=>2344343,
                         endscn=>2344456);
   ```
6. query v$logmnr_contents

   ```
   select sql_redo from v$logmnr_contents where seg_owner='JOHN';
   ```

> current output-
>       create table t1(id number);
>
> expected output-
>       create table john.t1 (id number);

Comment: What is your version?

Comment: Version 11.2.0.1.0

Comment: +DBMS_LOGMNR.PRINT_PRETTY_SQL has the same issue?

Comment: YES still the same result

Comment: Is it caused by dictionary or version or some packages are missing? or did i miss any step in between?